# What is the most popular generic collection data structure library for C?

Tags: c, data-structures, collections

I'm looking for a C library that provides generic collection data structures such as lists, associative arrays, sets, etc. The library should be stable and well tested. I'm basically looking for something better than the crappy C standard library.

What C libraries fit this description?

EDIT: I'd prefer that the library was cross-platform, but failing that, anything that works on Mac/Linux.

Comment: what system are you working on?

Comment: I'm on a Mac, but I'm looking for something cross-platform. It's not for embedded devices or anything fancy like that.

Comment: Why aren't you using C++, or a C-compatible wrapper around the STL container classes?

Comment: Many dupes including http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819416/standard-data-structure-library-in-c

Comment: I'm using C on purpose because I've always written in OO languages, and I want some experience in a non-OO language. That STL wrapper idea sounds good. I'll do that if there are no decent alternatives.

Comment: @Tom I can't see how a C wrapper around C++ templates can possibly work.

Comment: I've never tried it, but I imagine that you make a bunch of `extern "C"` functions that take a `void*` for whatever class it's operating on. e.g. `extern "C" void stl_vector_append(void* stl_vector, void* ptr_to_append);`

Comment: This looks like the way to do it: http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/mixing.html#cpp_from_c

Comment: @Tom But that code will have to be C++ code. I think you would be nuts to go this route - why not simply use C++?

Comment: As I commented above, I'm using C to get experience in C. I've already got plenty of experience in C++, and it's only a personal project.

Comment: There's a great library called C++ which does this... ;)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

if you are on linux, i would use [GLIB](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/stable/glib-data-types.html).  it provides all the helper libraries you would expect, plus its very well maintained and very active (always a +).  the link above is straight to the section on data structures, but there is plenty of other things in GLIB so take a look around!

Comment: +1, but glib is portable and certainly available on e.g. Windows too.

Comment: Unless the license is an issue.

Comment: @Alex GLib is licensed under LGPL, so there shouldn't be any issues

Comment: @qrdl indeed it is. For some reason I was always thinking it was licensed under GPL.

Answer (score 5):

[Apache Portable Runtime](http://apr.apache.org/) has collections (e.g. [hash table](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/0.9/group__apr__hash.html), [linked list](http://apr.apache.org/docs/apr/0.9/group__apr__ring.html)) and is, well, portable.