# Is there a standard set of libraries for dynamic strings, lists, and dictionaries in C?

Tags: c++, python, c, cython

I'm interested in getting into C to get close to the metal performance, but would like to write in a Pythonic style and don't want to roll my own dynamic strings, lists, and dictionaries. Cython is pretty good, but would like to know how to use dynamic variables in straight C if possible.

With C++ there is of course the STL, which will give you String, Vector, and Map. Certainly one possibility is to program in a C-like style in C++, using only those features. Is that the standard practice if you need dynamic variables in C?

Comment: `I'm interested in getting into C but would like to write in a Pythonic style`. Don't. This is C, not python. They're vastly different. If you want to write python, write python. If you want to write python in C, you'll just end up with horrible code.

Comment: @Falmarri: Certainly this is true, but at the same time it can be helpful to take the techniques learned in one language and apply it in another. Provided it doesn't make your code look like crap, of course.

Comment: [Container Class / Library for C](http://stackoverflow.com/q/305611/2509), [Any library for generic datatypes in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/649649/2509), [What is the most popular generic collection data structure library for C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3027797/2509), [Standard data structure library in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1819416/2509) none of which are exact duplicates, but the *answers* are more or less the same...

Comment: If you go writing Python in C, you're not going to get "close to the metal performance". Using the correct idioms, not the correct language, is what makes C fast and light.

Comment: @Ignacio: It takes a fair bit of experience in both languages to know when that's appropriate, though, especially with such fundamentally different languages as these.  For less experienced users, it's more likely to get in the way of learning.

Comment: @R: That's simply not true; Python has the serious overheads of GC, a high-level VM and dynamic typing, which makes the same algorithm written similarly in Python and C almost categorically much faster in C.

Comment: "If you want to write python in C, you'll just end up with horrible code" -- well, sure. I guess what i'm saying is that a large class of algorithms do use dynamic lists/strings/dicts. Any C code I write will likely have to use those, as I'm not dealing with fixed-width records. So given that Python has fairly nice strings/lists/dicts, was just looking for the idiomatic C equivalent. It can't be the solution for each developer to roll their own -- there has to be a winner out there -- but I don't know what that is, and google surprisingly doesn't provide any obvious answers. Hence the Q...

Comment: @Glenn and if you want to write it in anything like Pythonic style in C, you end up (wasting your time and) replicating most of the things that make the Python code slow.

Comment: @Karl, it depends what to call pythonic style - you can still have some "pythonic" features without a huge performance impact, for me this is a big part of what boost and C++0x try to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use C++; it has standard and highly-optimized versions of all of these.  There's absolutely no reason or benefit to limit yourself to C.

(ed: In other words, yes, that's a very standard practice.  Remember, there's no requirement to use any of C++'s features when using C++; by design, you can pick and choose.  I often disable exceptions, for example, since it leads to massively bloated executables.  There's simply no reason to write code in C.)

Comment: Many linux libs are written in C, and there are some people arguing that is more appropriate than C++ - isn't there a reason for that?

Comment: @7vies: People who have been using C for decades, who have dug trenches in their habit and history.  C was my first serious language, but today the only places I'll use it are 1: when contributing to an existing project that's in C, and 2: if a platform simply lacks C++ support (eg. some embedded systems).

Comment: @Glenn: for your second point, too bad gcc cannot "compile" to C.

Comment: I am pretty sure you can still get C++-to-C cross-compilers from **somewhere**...

Comment: @Karl: the problem with "somewhere" is that you can rarely rely on it.

Comment: @Karl, @7vies: Embedded software is generally so small--rarely more than a few thousand lines of code, as these systems often have on the order of 8-32k of flash space--that being stuck in C is usually not big enough of a problem to involve quirky code conversion.  At that size, lots of language features are out anyway--exceptions, anything involving vtables and all but the most basic of templates (like std::max) are usually avoided entirely.  That having been said, there is native g++ support for Atmel chips.

Comment: Still so, most kernel developers disagree with `There's simply no reason to write code in C`. Am just pointing out.

Comment: @jweyrich: Most kernel developers are wrong.  Am just pointing out.

Answer (score 4):

[glib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/) is pretty good and widely used:

> GLib provides the core application
>   building blocks for libraries and
>   applications written in C. It provides
>   the core object system used in GNOME,
>   the main loop implementation, and a
>   large set of utility functions for
>   strings and common data structures.

In fact, `glib` provides more (much more...) than just ADTs for strings, lists and dicts. But you can easily start by just using those parts, expanding later.

---

That said, don't think that having dynamic strings, lists and dictionaries will make your code Pythonic. The vast majority of C applications above some level of complexity have implementations of such data structures, but I'm not familiar with any such application written in "Pythonic style".

Comment: glib has a painfully ugly API; for most typical tasks, the C++ standard library leads to much more readable code.

Comment: Bad advice, the worst code I've seen was from people rooted in glib. Start using C++ facilities, standard library, boost, etc., don't start with C and #$%y libraries.

Comment: @Gene: Boost (or much of it, at least) isn't an improvement; the ugliest C++ template abuses imaginable are found there, tied with crypto++ for the worst C++ code you're ever likely to see.

Comment: @Glenn: totally agree! But are there any alternatives to boost (and templates)? Here, at SO, half of C++ related questions end up with a single reference to boost, as if it was the only option.

Comment: glib is basically the worst of both worlds (C and C++). Either write real C code, or use C++. Just like with natural languages, trying to translate the idioms of one programming language to another doesn't work; it generally results in extremely inefficient and ugly code.

Comment: @7vies: Templates aren't evil, and the C++ standard library uses them well--it's when you start writing entire algorithms as convoluted, crisscrosses of templates that things start to go bad.  When you see what looks like functional code, but with templates--turn and run the other way, as fast as you can.

Comment: @Glenn, I tend to consider C++ templates evil, just because they are poorly implemented, leading to limitations and consequently ugly workarounds. But in general is there any fundamental reason why functional style cannot be nicely combined with a low-level language?

Comment: @7vies: I'm the wrong person to ask, because I don't like functional style in the first place.  It always seems like nothing but people wanting to pretend they're doing math while they're programming.  It encourages writing large blobs of code rather than cleanly breaking code into logical statements; the resulting code is invariably needlessly opaque.

Comment: @Glenn, maybe functional style brought to extreme might result in such problems, but it looks to me that simple functional things like map/filter/foreach/lambda/... simplify programming a lot (python is a proof for this, isn't it?). Inverting the control flow as it is often done say in recursive factorial etc etc is a different thing, though.

Comment: @7vies: Some of Python's semi-functional constructs are fine, but, for example, almost every case of `map(lambda...` in Python is much clearer when written as a list comprehension.  The C++ functional-style functions like `std::bind1st` almost instantly become hard to follow.

Comment: @Glenn: I'd say the opposite. Procedural languages (including OOP) tends to lead to long blobs of vaguely related code, where a functional style typically allows you to naturally split everything up into functions of, at most, 2-3 lines. That is, assuming that by "functional style" we mean the style used in a *proper* functional language, and not the approximations enabled by C++ or other non-FP languages.