# Algorithm and data structure implementations for C programmers

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Are there any open source C libraries with common data structures?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/668501/are-there-any-open-source-c-libraries-with-common-data-structures)

What is the best source of algorithm and data structure implementations for C programmers? Links to an open source library or a book will do. (Please don't point to Sedgewick, as I already have his book).

Comment: possible duplicates: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/668501/are-there-any-open-source-c-libraries-with-common-data-structures http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1819416/standard-data-structure-library-in-c

Comment: @Nick Yes, a duplicate. I have voted to close this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Though I have not used [GDSL](http://home.gna.org/gdsl/) ( Generic Data Structures Library ) I think it's worth considering as it implements many frequently used data structures.

Answer (score 3):

[The Algorithm Design Manual by Steven Skiena](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0387948600)

[image]
<sub>(source: [alberton.info](http://www.alberton.info/images/amazon/big/the-algorithm-design-manual.jpg))</sub>

Comment: very good book, but includes only references to code libraries. It serves mostly as a guide for modeling problems.

Answer (score 2):

Another C library worth checking out, especially because it hasn't been mentioned in answers to this question and also the other duplicate questions: 
the *C Algorithms Library*, it can be found at http://c-algorithms.sourceforge.net/ and is covered by a BSD-style license, i.e. it can be freely used in any project. I've used it myself in several smaller programs without encountering any problems.

Comment: That was a useful link, Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Art of Computer Programming, Volume 1: Fundamental Algorithms (3rd Edition)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201896834)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Art_of_Computer_Programming

Comment: @Juds This is the definitive reference for any programmer. But I am looking for *implementations* in C.

Comment: Sorry. This one is for C.

http://www.amazon.com/Fundamentals-Data-Structures-Ellis-Horowitz/dp/0929306406