# std::unordered_set(int) container library for C

Tags: c, stl

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [C equivalent of C++ STL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11004252/c-equivalent-of-c-stl)

I am writing a program in C due to memory constraints on an embedded system. I need a `std::unordered_set<int>` to implement my algorithm. What STL-like libraries exist for C? If there isn't one which implements `std::unordered_set<int>` then what container can I use as an alternative?

Answer (score -1):

[sglib](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/) [red black tree container](http://sglib.sourceforge.net/doc/index.html#rbtree_exam) seems to provide what I need.

Comment: Hmm, in fact a *"red black tree container"* rather sounds like a `std::set` than a `std::unordered_set` (and I hope you know the difference between them).